# logs not displayed without a printfn at some point

Tags: .net, f#

When I try to run this little program, I've to comment out any of the 2 `printfn` lines in order to see any log when I run the code.

I can't figure out what I'm missing here (.NET newbie)

```
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console

let logger = LoggerFactory.Create(fun builder -> builder.AddConsole() |> ignore).CreateLogger("test")

let from whom =
    // printfn ""
    logger.LogInformation("hello " + whom)
    ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    //printfn ""
    do from "1" |> ignore
    0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, it wasn't related to f# at all, it's just that the program returns before the logger had the time to print anything.

This works as expected :

```
open Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.Console
open System.Threading

let logger = LoggerFactory.Create(fun builder -> builder.AddConsole() |> ignore).CreateLogger("test")

let from whom =
    logger.LogInformation("hello " + whom)
    ()

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv =
    do from "1" |> ignore
    do Thread.Sleep(10) // <- this was the missing part
    0
```

Comment: Answers to questions on StackOverflow are supposed to be useful to everybody. This workaround has no value at all. It just replaces one practical problem with another one, and is not a solution for the actual problem. The actual problem is how to ensure that all logs are flushed to the console before the program terminates.

Comment: In fact my issue was just to get some logs printed in the console and didn't understand why they didn't show up in the first minimal example. But actually, your point would be interesting too (but maybe quite context dependent).